# Enters the if statement where it shouldn't php Laravel9

Tags: php, laravel-9

Ok, here is the whole function stripped by not needed info:

```
$signups = $query->get(); COMMENT Here is it getting data

                   if($signups):
                        dump($signups); COMMENT Line 124
                        $invoice = new \App\Models\Invoice;
                        $invoice->created_by = \Auth::id();
                        $invoice->recipient_id = $club->id;
                        $invoice->recipient_type = 'App\Models\Club';
                        $invoice->sender_id = $sender->id;
                        $invoice->sender_type = $type;
                        $invoice->sender_name = $sender->name;
                        $invoice_nr = \App\Models\Invoice::GenerateInvoiceNumber($type, $sender->id);
                        dump($invoice_nr); COMMENT Line 133
                        $invoice->invoice_nr = $invoice_nr;
                        $invoice->invoice_reference = $sender->id.date('Y').$invoice_nr;
                        $invoice->save();
                        $sortorder = 0;

                        foreach($signups as $signup):
                            $sortorder++;
                            $invoice->expiration_date = (!$invoice->expiration_date || 
                            $invoice->expiration_date > $signup->Competition->signups_closing_date) ?  
                            $signup->Competition->signups_closing_date : $invoice->expiration_date;
                            $invoice->InvoiceRows()->create([
                                'description' => $signup->User->full_name.' '.$signup->Competition->name.' '
                                .$signup->Competition->date.' ('.(($signup->Competition->championships_id) ? 
                                $signup->Weaponclass->classname_general : $signup->Weaponclass->classname).')',
                                'quantity' => 1,
                                'unit' => _('st'),
                                'net_unit_amount' => $signup->registration_fee,
                                'vat_percent' => 0,
                                'vat_amount' => 0,
                                'row_net_amount' => 1 * $signup->registration_fee,
                                'row_vat_amount' => 0,
                                'row_sum_amount' => 1 * $signup->registration_fee,
                                'sortorder' => $sortorder
                            ]);
                            $invoice->Signups()->save($signup);
                        endforeach;
                        $amount = $invoice->InvoiceRows()->sum('row_sum_amount');
                        $invoice->amount = $amount;
                        $invoice->expiration_date = (!$invoice->expiration_date || $invoice->expiration_date < date('Y-m-d')) ? date('Y-m-d') : $invoice->expiration_date;
                        dump($invoice_nr);COMMENT Line 163
                        $invoice->save();         //Här sparas fakturan med rätt nummer
                        $invoices->push($invoice);
                   endif;

                    if(!$teamIds[0] == '') {
                        dump($teamIds);COMMENT Line 169
                        $query = \App\Models\Team::with('Competition', 'Weapongroup');
                        $query->whereIn('teams.id', $teamIds);
                         $query->orderBy('competitions_id') ->  orderBy('name');
                        $query->where(function($query) use ($club, $sender, $type){
                            $query->whereNull('invoices_id');
                            $query->where('clubs_id', $club->id);
                            $query->whereHas('Competition', function($query) use ($sender, $type){
                                $query->where('invoices_recipient_type', $type);
                                $query->where('invoices_recipient_id', $sender->id);
                            });
                        });
                        $teams = $query->get();
                    } else {
                        $teams = null;
                    }
                    dump($teams);COMMENT Line 185
                                    
                    if($teams):
                        $invoice = new \App\Models\Invoice;
                        $invoice->created_by = \Auth::id();
                        $invoice->recipient_id = $club->id;
                        $invoice->recipient_type = 'App\Models\Club';
                        $invoice->recipient_name = $club->name;
                        $invoice->sender_id = $sender->id;
                        $invoice->sender_type = $type;
                        $invoice->sender_name = $sender->name;
                        $invoice_nr = \App\Models\Invoice::GenerateInvoiceNumber($type, $sender->id);
                        $invoice->invoice_nr = $invoice_nr;
                        $invoice->invoice_reference = $sender->id.date('Y').$invoice_nr;
                        $invoice->save();

                        foreach($teams as $team):
                            $sortorder++;
                            $invoice->expiration_date = (!$invoice->expiration_date || 
                            $invoice->expiration_date > $team->Competition->signups_closing_date) ?  
                            $team->Competition->signups_closing_date : $invoice->expiration_date;
                            $invoice->InvoiceRows()->create([
                                'description' => _('Lag').': '.$team->name.' '.$team->Competition->name.' '
                                .$team->Competition->date.' ('.$team->Weapongroup->name.')',
                                'quantity' => 1,
                                'unit' => _('st'),
                                'net_unit_amount' => $team->registration_fee,
                                'row_sum_amount' => 1 * $team->registration_fee,
                                'sortorder' => $sortorder
                            ]);
                            $invoice->Teams()->save($team);
                        endforeach;

                        $amount = $invoice->InvoiceRows()->sum('row_sum_amount');
                        $invoice->amount = $amount;
                        $invoice->expiration_date = (!$invoice->expiration_date || 
                        $invoice->expiration_date < date('Y-m-d')) ? date('Y-m-d') : 
                        $invoice->expiration_date;
                        dump($invoice_nr);COMMENT Line 223
                        $invoice->save();
                        $invoices->push($invoice);
                    endif;
```

These are the dumps:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v4.1.9/clubinvoices?signup_ids=&team_ids=55
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 
  date         Mon, 09 May 2022 20:15:46 +0200         
  controller   "ClubInvoicesController"                
  source       InvoiceRepository.php on line 124       
  file         app/Repositories/InvoiceRepository.php  
 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection^ {#1567
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}

 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 
  date         Mon, 09 May 2022 20:15:46 +0200         
  controller   "ClubInvoicesController"                
  source       InvoiceRepository.php on line 133       
  file         app/Repositories/InvoiceRepository.php  
 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 

1507

 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 
  date         Mon, 09 May 2022 20:15:46 +0200         
  controller   "ClubInvoicesController"                
  source       InvoiceRepository.php on line 163       
  file         app/Repositories/InvoiceRepository.php  
 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 

1507

 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 
  date         Mon, 09 May 2022 20:15:46 +0200         
  controller   "ClubInvoicesController"                
  source       InvoiceRepository.php on line 169       
  file         app/Repositories/InvoiceRepository.php  
 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 

array:1 [
  0 => "55"
]

 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 
  date         Mon, 09 May 2022 20:15:46 +0200         
  controller   "ClubInvoicesController"                
  source       InvoiceRepository.php on line 185       
  file         app/Repositories/InvoiceRepository.php  
 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection^ {#1533
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Models\Team^ {#1564
COMMENT Here comes all the information about the team, cutted out.

------------ ---------------------------------------- 
  date         Mon, 09 May 2022 20:15:46 +0200         
  controller   "ClubInvoicesController"                
  source       InvoiceRepository.php on line 223       
  file         app/Repositories/InvoiceRepository.php  
 ------------ ---------------------------------------- 

1508
```

The last invoice number is the correct for the team
The previous invoice number 1507 is wrong because it enters the first if-statement if ($signups): where it shouldn't. Because of that an extra invoice is created first with nothing .

The signup now works without extra empty invoice because of this: if(!$teamIds[0] == '') { But this is not usable in signups.

So the problem is to get the if-statements to be entered when they should be and when not. I've tried everything but only succeeded with the if(!$teamIds[0] == '') {

In the controller is the array-settings:

```
        $signupIds = array();
        $signupsSelected = ($request->exists('signup_ids'));
        if ($request->has('signup_ids')) {
            $signupIds = explode(',', $request->get('signup_ids'));
        }

        $teamIds = array();
        $teamsSelected = ($request->exists('team_ids'));
        if ($request->has('team_ids')) {
            $teamIds = explode(',', $request->get('team_ids'));
        }
```

I have seen that if I use:  if(!$signups->isEmpty()): then it's not entered. But down in $teams I'm getting Undefined variable $sortorder in that case. I understand that we are dealing with

The Laravel system is upgraded from Laravel 5.3 where this code works and now to Laravel9 where it doesn't.

Comment: "_$teamIds is an array and is set to ""_" Where/how/why do you set it to an empty string? As you can see it has one element - that empty string. Just use `$teamIds = []` to set an empty array

Comment: Sorry, there's now just too much code to expect anyone to wade through. An extremely important skill in programming is breaking down a problem into smaller parts, and isolating the relevant code. First, stop debugging two things at once; pick either `$signupIds` or `$teamIds`. Then, look at where that variable is first set - in your second code snippet - and `dump()` it there. If it's not what you expect, then all the code *after* that point is irrelevant. If it's correct there, trace through the code looking for things that *change* that variable, and make a test file with just that code in.

Comment: If you can see what's happening in a simpler example, you can go back and fix the real code. If you can't, you'll end up with a [mcve], which will be much easier for someone else to help you with.

Comment: I have stripped the code now to a minimum and updated the dump list so it matches the code.

Comment: I'ts to prevent entering $teamIds part when a team is created.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. First the

```
if($signups):
```

needed to be changed to

```
if(!$signups->isEmpty()):
```

because it's a collective version of php array.

Also the

```
if($teamsId) {
```

needed to be

```
if(!$teamIds[0] == '') {
```

But I got an error Undefined variable $sortorder
because in the $teamIds there were a $sortorder = 0; missing.
Here in Laravel 9 it was necessary obviously.

So for now, I'm glad and I want to thank you all for your help and effort.

Answer (score -2):

Try empty function:    `if(!empty($teamIds)){`

Comment: No,it enters the code despite that. I put a dump($teamIds); directly after the if(!empty($teamIds)){ and it dumps the same so I'm really in there.

Comment: It has _one_ element, so it is not empty

Comment: Is array:1 [
  0 => ""
] one element?

Comment: If I create a team then this array:1 [
  0 => ""
] is being array:1 [
  0 => "27"
] or whatever the team id is. Then it's going through and make an invoice but also an empty one.

Comment: Use `if(!empty($teamIds[0])){`

Comment: @raffodog That `1` in `array:1` says it has `1` element

Comment: Ok, if so how do I determine  between "" and "56" when at "" I will NOT go into the if statement but with "56" I will? I can't figure that out.

Comment: ```if($teamIds[0] == '')```

Comment: Quiet Molly
That seems to work when I create a **signup**. I won't get into teamIds, so no zero invoices.  I also used it here if(!$signups[0] == ''): but then I'm getting error "Undefined array key 0" on that line when I try to make a **team**. So for signups ok but for teams not.

Comment: @Quite Molly - So if I put this  if(!$signups == ''): signups works well. But if I create a team I'm also entering signups and an extra empty invoice is created.

Comment: @Quite Molly - I'm getting this dump after if(!$signups == ''): **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection^ {#1567
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false** so I'm in to make an empty invoice.